# Find the probability distribution of $Y - \min(X, Y)$ for $X \sim\mathrm{Unif}[0, 2]$ , $Y \sim \mathrm{Exp}(1)$, $X \perp Y$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I do know how to compute the pdf of $\min(X, Y),$ i.e. $\mathbb{P}(U \geq u) = \mathbb{P} (U \geq X)\mathbb{P} (U \geq Y)$. Resulting in $\mathbb{P}(U \geq u) = (1 - \frac{u}{2})(e^{-u})$ The rest is CDf-PDF calculation.

I get stuck in the subtracting $Y$ from the minimum of $X$ and $Y$ step.

Comment: $Y-\min(X,Y)$ is $Y-X$ if $X\le Y$ and $0$ if $X>Y$, so find the CDF accordingly. Anyway you are missing the word 'independence' of $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: Why change existing questions rendering answers meaningless? If you have another question, ask in a separate post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume $X,\,Y$ are independent. I'll make this as unmessy as possible. Since we want the distribution of$$Z:=Y-\min(X,\,Y)=\max(Y-X,\,0),$$we'll start by determining the distribution of $Y-X$, which has minimum $-2$. For $t\ge-2$,$$\begin{align}P(Y-X\le t)&=P(Y\le t+X)\\&=\int_0^2\frac12P(Y\le t+x)dx\\&=\int_{\max(0,\,-t)}^2\frac12P(Y\le t+x)dx\\&\left(\because x<\max(0,\,-t)\implies X>x\lor Y\not\le t+x\right)\\&=\frac12\left[x+e^{-t}e^{-x}\right]_{\max(0,\,-t)}^2.\end{align}$$Call the above function $F(t)$. The minimum value of $Z$ is $0$. For $z\ge0$,$$P(Z\le z)=P(Y-X\le z\land0\le z)=P(Y-X\le z)=F(z).$$In particular, the CDF is $F(z)$ for $z\ge0$ but $0$ for $z<0$, even though $F(t)>0$ for all $t>-2$. For $z\ge0$,$$F(z)=\frac12\left[x+e^{-z}e^{-x}\right]_0^2=1-\frac12(1-e^{-2})e^{-z}.$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Could you elaborate on the bounds of the integral as well as $\mathbb{P}(Y \leq t + x)$?

Comment: @JamesJohns See edit.

Answer (score 0):

The joint pdf is given by $f_{X,Y}(x,y)=f_X(x) f_Y(y)=\frac{1}{2}e^{-y}$. Hence, the probability $X<Y$ is given by
$$
P(X<Y)=\int_0^2\int_{x}^\infty\frac{1}{2}e^{-y}\,\mathrm{d}y\mathrm{d}x=\int_0^2 \frac{1}{2}e^{-x}\,\mathrm{d}x=\frac{1}{2}(1-e^{-2}).
$$
Therefore, $P(X\geq Y)=1-\frac{1}{2}(1-e^{-2})$. Let $Z=Y-\min(X,Y)$. Then $P(Z\leq z)=P(X<Y)P(Z\leq z |X<Y) + P(X\geq Y)P(Z\leq z | X\geq Y)$. If $X<Y$, then $Z=Y-X$ and if $X\geq Y$, then $Z=Y-Y=0$.

Consider when $z\geq 0$. Then $P(Z\leq z | X<Y)=P(Y\leq z+X)=\int_0^2\int_0^{x+z}\frac{1}{2}e^{-y} \,\mathrm{d}y\mathrm{d}x.$ For the other term, $P(Z\leq z|X\geq Y)=P(0\leq z | X\geq Y)=1.$

Consider when $z\in(-2,0)$. Then $P(Z\leq z | X<Y)=P(Y\leq z+X)=\int_{-z}^2\int_0^{x+z}\frac{1}{2}e^{-y} \,\mathrm{d}y\mathrm{d}x.$ For the other term, $P(Z\leq z|X\geq Y)=P(0\leq z | X\geq Y)=0.$

Finally, when $z\leq-2$, both conditional CDFs are zero. After doing all of the calculus, you should get a piecewise $F_Z (z)$.